# How to sum the KroneckerDelta[] in equation?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, algebraic-manipulation

How to sum the `KroneckerDelta`s in following equation?
`k`, `p1`, `p2`, `q1`, and `q2` all are from $ -∞ $ to $ \infty $.
Now, I use `Block` to define each `KroneckerDelta` realation, for example:

```
test1 = (KroneckerDelta[-k, -p2] KroneckerDelta[p1, -q2] KroneckerDelta[-q1, k-p1-p2-q1-q2] - KroneckerDelta[-k, -p1] KroneckerDelta[p2, -q2] KroneckerDelta[-q1, k-p1-p2-q1-q2]) Sinh[Subscript[λ, k]]

Block[{k = p2, q2 = -p1},
    KroneckerDelta[-k, -p2] KroneckerDelta[p1, -q2] KroneckerDelta[-q1, k-p1-p2-q1-q2] Sinh[Subscript[λ, k]]
]
+
Block[{k = p1, q2 = -p2},
    -KroneckerDelta[-k, -p1] KroneckerDelta[p2, -q2] KroneckerDelta[-q1, k-p1-p2-q1-q2] Sinh[Subscript[λ, k]]
]
```

The output is

```
-Sinh[Subscript[λ, p1]] + Sinh[Subscript[λ, p2]]
```

You can see, if only one equation this is simple, but when I have a lot of `KroneckerDelta`, it will be really complicated.

How can I use the sum function or other instrutions of MMA to get the final result?

Comment: Does your problem go away if you define `test2 = test1 /. Subscript[\[Delta], x_, y_] -> KroneckerDelta[x, y]` and use the [builtin Kronecker delta function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerDelta.html) instead of a subscripted delta? They look the same but aren't in `FullForm` or `InputForm`.

Comment: In my notebook is KroneckerDelta, when I paste it to stack, it was wrong. And now I have fix the problem you propose.